# Create an array from a .dat file using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, file

I need to convert this file.dat in an array using Javascript for an exercise.

```
    Team            P     W    L   D    F      A     Pts
 1. Arsenal         38    26   9   3    79  -  36    87
 2. Liverpool       38    24   8   6    67  -  30    80
 3. Manchester_U    38    24   5   9    87  -  45    77
 4. Newcastle       38    21   8   9    74  -  52    71
 5. Leeds           38    18  12   8    53  -  37    66
 6. Chelsea         38    17  13   8    66  -  38    64
 7. West_Ham        38    15   8  15    48  -  57    53
 8. Aston_Villa     38    12  14  12    46  -  47    50
 9. Tottenham       38    14   8  16    49  -  53    50
10. Blackburn       38    12  10  16    55  -  51    46
11. Southampton     38    12   9  17    46  -  54    45
12. Middlesbrough   38    12   9  17    35  -  47    45
13. Fulham          38    10  14  14    36  -  44    44
14. Charlton        38    10  14  14    38  -  49    44
15. Everton         38    11  10  17    45  -  57    43
16. Bolton          38     9  13  16    44  -  62    40
17. Sunderland      38    10  10  18    29  -  51    40
-------------------------------------------------------
18. Ipswich         38     9   9  20    41  -  64    36
19. Derby           38     8   6  24    33  -  63    30
20. Leicester       38     5  13  20    30  -  64    28
```

Surfing the web I have found a code to parse the file and creating the array. I works but now **but** I met some problems: because in the final array I have a lot of undesired characters as whitespaces, numbers before the team names and the row formed only by -----

This is the Html code and my script.js with th

```js
function fileToArray(str, delimiter = /[#\s,]+/g) {
  // slice from start of text to the first \n index
  // use split to create an array from string by delimiter
  const headers = str.slice(0, str.indexOf("\n")).split(delimiter);
  console.log(headers);
  const rows = str.slice(str.indexOf("\n") + 1).split(delimiter);
  console.log(rows);

  // Map the rows
  // split values from each row into an array
  // use headers.reduce to create an object
  // object properties derived from headers:values
  // the object passed as an element of the array

  const arr = rows.map(function(row) {
    const values = row.split(delimiter);
    const el = headers.reduce(function(object, header, index) {
      object[header] = values[index];
      return object;
    }, {});
    return el;
  });

  // return the array
  return arr;
  console.log(arr);
}


const data = fileToArray(text);
var Json = JSON.stringify(data);
console.log(Json);
```

Using the metacharcter /[#\s,]+/g I was able to eliminate some whitespaces, but now I don't know how improve the code.

**EDIT**: The result must be a JSON like this:

```
  {
    "0": {
        "Team":"Arsenal", 
        "P": 38,
        "W":26,
        "L":9,
        "D":3,
        "F":79,
        "A":36,
        "Pts": 87
    },
    "1": {
        "Team":"Liverpool", 
        "P": 38,
        "W":24,
        "L":8,
        "D":6,
        "F":67,
        "A":30,
        "Pts": 80
    }, 
       ... 
}
```

Comment: You want to first split array of rows using `let arr = dat.split('\n').slice(1)`  then in map split each row string with your delimiter

Comment: I made you a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this

I destruct the lines after trimming them

If you want to KEEP the number and have objects instead of arrays

```js
function fileToArray(text) {
  const lines = text.split(/\n/); // split on \n
  const header = lines[0].trim().split(/\s+/); // split on whitespace after trimming
  return [...lines.slice(1).map(line => {
    // ignore the number and the dash
    const [number, team, p, w, l, d, f, ignore2, a, pts] = line.trim().split(/\s+/);
    return {[number]: {team, p, w, l, d, f, a, pts}}
  })]
}

console.log(
  fileToArray(text) 
)
```

```html
<script>
  const text = `         Team            P     W    L   D    F      A     Pts
     1. Arsenal         38    26   9   3    79  -  36    87
     2. Liverpool       38    24   8   6    67  -  30    80
     3. Manchester_U    38    24   5   9    87  -  45    77
     4. Newcastle       38    21   8   9    74  -  52    71
     5. Leeds           38    18  12   8    53  -  37    66
     6. Chelsea         38    17  13   8    66  -  38    64
     7. West_Ham        38    15   8  15    48  -  57    53
     8. Aston_Villa     38    12  14  12    46  -  47    50
     9. Tottenham       38    14   8  16    49  -  53    50
    10. Blackburn       38    12  10  16    55  -  51    46
    11. Southampton     38    12   9  17    46  -  54    45
    12. Middlesbrough   38    12   9  17    35  -  47    45
    13. Fulham          38    10  14  14    36  -  44    44
    14. Charlton        38    10  14  14    38  -  49    44
    15. Everton         38    11  10  17    45  -  57    43
    16. Bolton          38     9  13  16    44  -  62    40
    17. Sunderland      38    10  10  18    29  -  51    40
    -------------------------------------------------------
    18. Ipswich         38     9   9  20    41  -  64    36
    19. Derby           38     8   6  24    33  -  63    30
    20. Leicester       38     5  13  20    30  -  64    28`
</script>
```

Here is an array version

```js
function fileToArray(text) {
  const lines = text.split(/\n/); // split on \n
  const header = lines[0].trim().split(/\s+/); // split on whitespace after trimming
  return [header, ...lines.slice(1).map(line => {
    // ignore the number and the dash
    const [ignore1, team, p, w, l, d, f, ignore2, a, pts] = line.trim().split(/\s+/);
    return [team, p, w, l, d, f, a, pts];
  })]
}

console.log(
  fileToArray(text) 
)
```

```html
<script>
  const text = `         Team            P     W    L   D    F      A     Pts
     1. Arsenal         38    26   9   3    79  -  36    87
     2. Liverpool       38    24   8   6    67  -  30    80
     3. Manchester_U    38    24   5   9    87  -  45    77
     4. Newcastle       38    21   8   9    74  -  52    71
     5. Leeds           38    18  12   8    53  -  37    66
     6. Chelsea         38    17  13   8    66  -  38    64
     7. West_Ham        38    15   8  15    48  -  57    53
     8. Aston_Villa     38    12  14  12    46  -  47    50
     9. Tottenham       38    14   8  16    49  -  53    50
    10. Blackburn       38    12  10  16    55  -  51    46
    11. Southampton     38    12   9  17    46  -  54    45
    12. Middlesbrough   38    12   9  17    35  -  47    45
    13. Fulham          38    10  14  14    36  -  44    44
    14. Charlton        38    10  14  14    38  -  49    44
    15. Everton         38    11  10  17    45  -  57    43
    16. Bolton          38     9  13  16    44  -  62    40
    17. Sunderland      38    10  10  18    29  -  51    40
    -------------------------------------------------------
    18. Ipswich         38     9   9  20    41  -  64    36
    19. Derby           38     8   6  24    33  -  63    30
    20. Leicester       38     5  13  20    30  -  64    28`
</script>
```

Comment: Ok. I must put this inside the fileToArray function?

Comment: It replaces your code

Comment: I have precise instructions: the file must me read!

Comment: EDIT:  I resolve this point. Now I need to transform in create a associative array.

Comment: See updated first example